# Dual boot partition accessibility problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Win 10. Got a 1 TB hard disk. Allocated ~200 GB for Windows and left the rest as unallocated space and installed Ubuntu in it. Now that ~720 GB is not being accessed by Windows. I cannot run the partition operations in Windows.

The solution I'm thinking is to just shrink the Ubuntu partition to about 100 GB and created another partition from the remaining space in NTFS format so that it serves as a common partition.

Will my method work?
Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure that fast startup is off in Windows. That is always on hibernation and there does not seem to be a way to unmount a data partition in Windows. If hibernated you will not be able to write into it and if you do, data will be lost as the hibernation restores everything to as it was before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share partition between Windows and Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49181/how-to-share-partition-between-windows-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... This should work just fine. The problem is that Windows can not read Ext4 formatted partitions.

Comment: That is why I'm thinking of partitioning the common partition in NTFS format.
Thank you :)